# Question won't let me post answer, saying I need 10 reputation. I have 101. What gives?

Tags: support, reputation

Wanted to post an answer to [ssh connection to server closed after authentication immediately](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166975/ssh-connection-to-server-closed-after-authentication-immediately), but it says

```
protected by Community♦ Dec 17 '14 at 23:23

Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality 
answers, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site. 

Would you like to answer one of these unanswered questions instead?
```

At the top of the screen I see 101 reputation (mainly because I have rep on other sites).  Refreshing (or shift-refresh) doesn't do it.  I posted my answer as a comment.  Oh well

Comment: It actually says "To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site.". Have you?

Comment: When I access that post, it actually says exactly what I copied and pasted into my post above.

Comment: Strange, why would you get a different message? Here is the complete text I see: "This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site.".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have at least 200 reputation on any site of the Stack Exchange network, you will receive an ["association bonus"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/) of 100 reputation points when you create a new account on any other site of the network. That's why you have a reputation of 101 here.

Now, the question you tried to answer is [protected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions), this means that you must have earned at least 10 reputation points **on this site** in order to answer it. Since you have not gained any reputation *on this site* yet, the system won't let you answer.

Don't let that discourage you, you can still answer the vast majority of questions here, only a very few are protected. Go forth and answer!

Comment: I would encourage you to change this policy--or at least to clarify it.  I might think I had "earned" those 100 points on your site based on my participation in other sites.  I do like to help people, but don't really have time to be answering random questions on your site... and unix/linux isn't my strong point in any case.  But I did happen to figure out an answer to at least one cause of this problem, and it's worth thinking about whether rep on another site makes that person worth some trust.

Comment: @NatKuhn first, a clarification: this is not "our" policy, it's not something we chose as a community. This is just the way that the Stack Exchange sites work and we (the U&L folks) can't change it. That said, I quite agree that the message could be clearer. I also understand that it's frustrating but it's a necessary protection from drive-by spammers. There are only 128 protected questions out of the ~61K on the site. I realize this is annoying to you but it's hardly a big problem. Rep on another site certainly makes someone worthy of trust, that's why you get 100 free rep!

Comment: @NatKuhn - I would encourage you to slice that particular piece of the question you've figured out an answer to, and create your own Q & A to it.

Comment: @terdon, sorry to be cranky about this, but it seems that (a) there is a bug here as noted in the comment to the question--people are getting different explanation messages; (b) at least one of these messages is worded in an unclear way; (c) if the purpose is to avoid spam or "thanks!" or "me, too" comments, wouldn't rep on another stackexchange site be sufficient for that? Is there a stackexchange meta site (meta meta?) where bugs and issues of this sort could be addressed, since they can't be addressed here?

Comment: @slm, thank you for your constructive suggestion.  As penance for my crankiness, I will do just as you say, clearly flagging it as a duplicate.

Comment: OK, @slm, I have posted it here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193044/ssh-connection-to-server-closed-immediately-after-authentication/193045#193045.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @natkuhn a) you're seeing that message because you tried to answer, the one mentioned in the comment is on the actual question, not the pop-up that appears if you attempt to answer. b) true c) popular questions appear in the side bar on all sites and bring in visitors from other communities. This often results in people who don't understand the site's scope posting answers or come to that don't really belong.  Protecting is a way to avoid that. The meta meta is http://meta.stackexchange.com